# Can't prevent form to submit when javascript validation fails

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am learning Javascript and this might be a very stupid question but I am running nuts. I was trying all sort of things to prevent a form to be submitted with no luck so now I placed a very simple function that will always return false. Still the form is submitted, can someone explain why and what do I need to change? THANKS!

```
<form action="http://students.open.ac.uk/mct/tt284/reflect/reflect.php" method="post" name="displayTimeTable" onsubmit="return toSubmit();">

<some html>.....

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

`

and the javascript

```
function toSubmit(){
  alert('I will not submit');
  return false;
```

}

Comment: have you closed the `<form>` tag using `</form>`??

Comment: your code seems to be working perfect, See this [FIDDLE >>](http://jsfiddle.net/3tjnF/)

Comment: Just use Javascript to improve visitors experience. They might turn it off. So you need to also do validation at the server end.

Comment: I am using Fiddle since the beginning. The HTML tags are properly closed.

Comment: @Ed Heal, I know, but I am doing an exercise for my studies where I need to do client validation before executing the server's validation.

Comment: but your code is working perfect in fiddle, try changing it to `true`, you can see its working. May be due to some other errors, have you debugged??

Comment: check your console for any errors

Comment: @PrasanthKC what console would that be? It is not working, the form is always posted even if the js returns true or false...

Comment: @JoyAdamson JavaScript console, on most browsers clicking F12 should bring up dev tools, such console is part of them and will show you the JS errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try an onclick event on the submit button instead of onSubmit

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return toSubmit();"/>
```

Comment: Change the type to 'button'.

Comment: @JoyAdamson can you create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net? A button can't submit the form by itself, it have to call the submit function. But in your case it must work with the submit button too.

Comment: @JoyAdamson i think there is the problem.. you are checking it in fiddle only rite?? in fiddle such script should be put in same frame where html is written, like this [FIDDLE >>](http://jsfiddle.net/E7bns/1/)

Comment: @JoyAdamson see your fiddle now... The function will not work in the script frame. If moved it in the HTML block, it works now.

Comment: @JoyAdamson Better first you try stuffs in standalone self-created html files and test it locally, frameworks like fiddle may have bugs.

Comment: @JoyAdamson your fiddle didn't work because by default the scope is "onLoad" meaning whatever functions you write, they are local to the window `onload` event and can't be called from within buttons. See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7bns/3/) where same code works after choosing "No wrap" option.

Comment: @PrasanthKC no bug, you just need to know how to use jsfiddle properly, see my previous comment.

Comment: @ShadowWizard i wont say that this issue is due to any bug in fiddle, i just given an advise that it will be better to test locally instead of depending some frameworks, that's why i said `may have bugs`. And you can't say a framework is completely bug free until you play and check with each and every possibilities. I can show you a bug in fiddle if you are interested.

Comment: @PrasanthKC of course, but jsfiddle is super useful and this specific case is not a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard i don't have other opinion on that, fiddle is 110% useful, and in this case it is not a bug also and i never say so.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/yQ2gL/1/

```
<script>
    var onSubmit = function() {
        return false;
    }
</script>
<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return onSubmit();">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```